# Multiple unwanted lines in Photoshop CC when using Select Tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop

**Adobe Photoshop Version:** 2015.0.0 20150529.r.88

Recently I upgraded Photoshop CC to its 2015 version. Now the problem here is that i get strip lines when selecting any particular area using marquee tool or whenever i use magic wand tool.

Whenever I try to select a particular area, it automatically selects a straight path instead of what i selected.

In the first image you can see internal segments of line as if i am using slice tool. How can i disable those internal lines. I get these when I use select tool to select an area.

Here is a sample screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Performance
2. Tick to enable 'use graphics processor'
3. Click the advanced settings button
4. Set the drawing mode to advanced
5. Tick 'Use graphics processor...'
6. Tick 'Use OpenGL'
7. Tick 'Anti-alias guides and paths'

[image: Screenshot]

(For those Googleing weird Photoshop marquee tool lines glitch bug can't deselect)